# Router part of PWA opens blank on device (with Vue)

Tags: vue.js, router, progressive-web-apps

I built 2 PWA based on Vue (with Vue UI templates, with router and PWA already set up) but I get on both the same issue: after I add to Homescreen on device, when I open it from the app icon, the router viez doesn't show up and stays blank until I click on a router link. I don't understand why.

Example of one of them, my portfolio:

URL [Link](https://lightwolf-studios.com)

GitHub [Link](https://github.com/LightBen/lightwolf-studios)

Some parts of files here that I think related to the issue:

**router.js**:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: 'index.html',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    }
  ]
})
```

**firebase.json**:

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Comment: I've got the exact same problem. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Hi @ArjendeJong , I didn't have time to look for a solution but the problem is more precise to me now: it should have a better server configuration (and I know nothing in server lol). When I remove history mode, it works most of the time. I get the hash for now in the url, not the sexiest but until I understand what to do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit:
Checkout @webmint answer below, probably solve problem im better and clean way.

Orginal Post:

I solved my problem adding an alias to start page in routes (in my case "Login")

in manifest.json:

```
{
...
"start_url": "index.html",
...
}
```

in router config:

```
let router = new Router({
...
  routes: [
    {   path: '/index.html',
        component: Login,
        alias: '/'
    },
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'login',
        component: Login
    },
...
```

Comment: The default "/index.html" start_url is fine. The missing part is just "{ path: '/index.html', component: Home }" in the router.

Comment: Brilliant! So glad I found this, and well done for figuring it out.

Comment: Please  check comment of @DaveStewart at this page before use this adwice

Answer (score 7):

Had same issue. Turns out that solution is quite simple. You have to add/change this in manifest.json

```
"start_url": "/",
"scope": "/"
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Having index.html as the "start_url" just sends Vue to the route "index.html/index.html" which is why you need to alias it. Add an alert() in a router.beforeEach() and you will see

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of repeating kaligari's answer, I'd say that the required part is only

`{ path: '/index.html', component: Home }`

in the router config. You can also use an alias to make it look better on the client. Although, when used as a PWA, this makes no difference since the address bar is not visible.

`{ path: '/index.html', component: Home, alias: '/' }`

Comment: Thanks a lot, and yes, Just by putting path indec.html it workes (and I added the alias for desktop anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `vue.config.js`:

```
pwa: {
  workboxOptions: {
    navigateFallback: '/index.html',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If it can help someone, here is what worked for me (after trying a lot of the above solutions and other ones on the web...) :

**Context:** PWA with Vue.js CLI 3.

**Problem:** After installing the URL on the "desktop" through the "Add to home screen" option in Safari, clicking on the icon opened a white page.

The same on Android (Chrome) was working perfectly.

---

I solved it with the following config:

**manifest.json**

```
  ...
  "start_url": "/index.html",
  ...
```

**router.json (includes some Firebase config elements)**

```
//......
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            redirect: {
                path: '/projects'
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'Login',
            component: Login,
        },
        {
            path: '/projects',
            name: 'Projects',
            component: Projects,
            meta: {
                requiresAuth: true
            }
        },
        //......
    ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(x => x.meta.requiresAuth);
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
        next('/login');
    } else if (requiresAuth && currentUser) {
        next();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

export default router;
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    pwa: {
        name: 'Xxxxxxxxxx',
        themeColor: '#000000',
        msTileColor: '#000000',
        appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
        appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',
        workboxOptions: {
            navigateFallback: '/index.html',
        },
    }
};
```