# My Vue PWA app shows white blank page on iOS

Tags: ios, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

I am currently working one a Vuejs PWA app (using Vue CLI 3). My app works fine on Android, Windows, and macOS, but it only shows a white blank page on ios. More specifically, when I use an iPhone and access my app with Safari or Chrome, it all shows a white page. When I add my app to the home screen of the iPhone, when I open it up, it still shows a white page.

this is [link](https://hostel-renting.netlify.app) to my app.

[White blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDasL.png)

I have tried many workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092009/router-part-of-pwa-opens-blank-on-device-with-vue) but it not work.

here are some parts of my code:
vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: ['vuetify'],
  pwa: {
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      swSrc: 'src/config/firebase-messaging-sw.js',
      exclude: [/\.map$/, /_redirects/],
    },
    manifestOptions: {
      start_url: 'index.html',
    },
    name: 'AppName',
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
  },
};
```

router

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "RenterMainView",
      component: RenterView,
      children: [
        {
          path: "index.html",
          name: "Home",
          component: Home,
          meta: { guest: true },
          alias: ""
        },
        {
          path: "detail/:typeId",
          name: "HostelDetail",
          component: HostelDetail,
          meta: { guest: true }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (window.$cookies.get('jwt') === null) {
      // not logged in
      next({
        name: 'Login',
        params: { nextUrl: to.path, preUrl: from.path },
      });
    } else {
      // logged in
      const role = window.$cookies.get('role');
      if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.is_vendor)) {
        if (role === 'vendors') {
          next();
        } else {
          next(from.path);
        }
      } else if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.is_admin)) {
        if (role === 'admins') {
          next();
        } else {
          next(from.path);
        }
      } else if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.is_renter)) {
        if (role === 'renters') {
          next();
        } else {
          next(from.path);
        }
      } else {
        next();
      }
    }
  } else if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.guest)) {
    // not require authen
    next();
  } else {
    // not require authen
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Any updates? I don't have ios access but a friend found the same issue when accessing on iphone. Interestingly my app has a background color which is rendered in their screenshot.

Comment: I was use Firebase Cloud Messing which is not working on Ios, that why it show a white page. Nothing related to pwa. After I disable FMC on ios, everything was fine.

Comment: using this code: `if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {  }`

Answer (score 0):

#### Try changing the start_url

I found that on

- Chrome Windows
- Chrome MacOS
- Android

I was OK to use quite a wide variety of `start_url` values, such as the "index.html" that you have, or "/index.html", etc.

However on iOS, I had to use

```
start_url: "."
```

The other values were fine on the other platforms, but gave a blank white screen on iOS.

#### Try creating a blank PWA with the Vue CLI

Does that work correctly on iOS?
Then step by step change it to contain your app.
Find out where it breaks.

That's how I found the start_url issue.

Comment: here it is stated that it should be "/" instead of "." or "/index.html"
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/blank-screen-after-pwa-update-on-ios/72504/4

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this could help someone. In this project, I make an PWA app using Vue, and I use Firebase Cloud Messagging to send notification from server to client. Unfortunaly, due to some restrictions on iOS, FCM doesn't work on it, that is why the application show a white page on iOS. So, the solution is to disable FCM on iOS

```
if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) { // your code go here }
```

using above code to disable FCM on firebase service worker file